# Swift : How to read the files from the folder

Tags: swift, swift2

How to read or access the files from the folder. And the folder is added in the supporting files folder.

Could you please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Files_in_Swift_on_iOS_8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load a file via pathForResource and read it via NSData.
This is an example of json file:

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("yourFileName", ofType: "yourFileExtension") {
        do {
            let data = try NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
            if let newObj = (try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:[])) as? NSDictionary {
                //on success do what you need...
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            //failure...
        }
    }
```